# shared item in a node's property in Neo4j

Tags: join, neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database.
I have nodes that each have a list property; let's call it `variant_list`. (Contains a list of strings.)
Here is an example of 3 nodes in JSON format:

```json
[
{
  "identity": 1,
  "properties": {
    "variant_list": ["xx","yy", "zzz" ],
    "name": "First"
  }
},
{
  "identity": 2,
  "properties": {
    "variant_list": ["xx","pp", "ww" ],
    "name": "Second"
  }
},
{
  "identity": 3,
  "properties": {
    "variant_list": ["nn","pp", "ll" ],
    "name": "Third"
  }
}
]
```

I would like to write a query in cypher that gets the pairs (1,2) and (3,2) because (1 and 2) share the `xx` string, and (2 and 3) share `pp` in their `variant_list`.

My database has 2 million nodes. So I want to consider the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a choice but to a cartesian product of each node to another node. Then check that a is not the same with b and any item in a.variant_list is found in b.variant_list.

apoc.periodic.iterate will create a batch of 10k rows of node "a" then match it with node "b".  However, iterate works only when you create nodes or relationships so either you create a node "Result" or do a relationship connecting a to b.  In my example below, I create a new node Result to store the pairs.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (a:TestNode) RETURN a as row",
"WITH row
MATCH (b:TestNode) WHERE row < b
AND ANY(i IN row.variant_list WHERE i IN b.variant_list)
WITH row, b
CREATE (r:Result) SET r.pairs = [row.name, b.name]",
 {batchSize:10000, parallel:true, retries:0});

Result:
╒════════════════════════════╕
│"result"                    │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│{"pairs":["First","Second"]}│
├────────────────────────────┤
│{"pairs":["Second","Third"]}│
└────────────────────────────┘
```

If you want to create a relationship between the nodes, you can replace the CREATE with this command

```
MERGE (row)-[:PAIRS_WITH]->(b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, Could I add any index or something to speed up this comparison (Or parallelization config or something?)? Because I am now running this query with `LIMIT 1` at the end but have not gotten any result yet. :) thank you.

Comment: You can add index for your other queries but not for this since you are doing a FULL scan of all testNodes.

Comment: I updated my answer to make use of parallel batching.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. PS There is now a table format in the editor.

Comment: I did not get any notification when the response was updated, but I did get a notification for comment. So I think sending a comment was a good idea. anyway, thank you both. I wish you good luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: @Ali Askers get notification of new answers. See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Otherwise: If you click to follow a post (Q or A) you will get notice of its changes & comments. Read the [help] & google Q&A using 'site:' at [meta] & [meta.se] re how the site works.